# spring-ldap use ldaps connect to ActiveDirectory

Tags: active-directory, ldap, spring-ldap

I want to create a ldap account (with password) or change account passwords with spring-ldap, so I follow some instructions to export a certificate from AD and import it to jdk, after that I change the protocol and port of the url to `ldaps://AD-SERVER-TEST.test.com:636`, I think It's all I have to do. But I got a `javax.naming.OperationNotSupportedException: [LDAP: error code 53 - 00002077: SvcErr: DSID-031908B4, problem 5003 (WILL_NOT_PERFORM), data 0` error. It means spring-ldap doesn't connect AD through secure connection.
I search from the web, nothing help. But I can change the password with native ldap support, for example , `javax.naming.ldap.InitialLdapContext.createSubcontext()` to create a new account, all the ldap config is the same as spring-ldap. So do I need make more changes to spring-ldap ?
the native ldap enviroment config like this, nothing special:

```java
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, adminName);
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, adminPassword);
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_PROTOCOL, "ssl");
        String ldapURL = "ldaps://AD-SERVER-TEST.test.com:636";
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, ldapURL);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are still in this i suggest you to check how to correctly import the SSL certificate.

Here explain how to do that with InstallCert: https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2018/07/ldap-authentication-active-directory-authentication-java-spring-security-example.html#axzz7zyBjZQeo

or make this function when you call your endpoint to always trust certificate

```
public static void trustSelfSignedSSL() {
        try {
            SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            X509TrustManager tm = new X509TrustManager() {

                public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] xcs, String string) throws CertificateException {
                }

                public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] xcs, String string) throws CertificateException {
                }

                public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                    return null;
                }
            };
            ctx.init(null, new TrustManager[] { tm }, null);
            SSLContext.setDefault(ctx);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

For more details about ssl i suggest you to enable ssl debug. In your main file add: `System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "ssl:handshake, keymanager");`